# Why doesn't Generate Columns work for a DataGrid bound to the DataView of a DataTable?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bout to the DataView property of a typed DataTable however when I click Generate Columns I get "You must set ItemsSource before you can perform this action". Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. See the XAML below:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Margin="0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataView/}" 
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1},
      Path=TransferSchedulesView/}">
```

TransferSchedulesView is a property on my MainWindow, it exposes the DataView property of a typed DataTable member. Any suggestions as to where I went wrong here?

Comment: Does it happen in design mode?

Comment: Yes, in the Properties Window for the DataGrid there are 'Generate Columns' and 'Edit Porperty-Bound Coliumns' link buttons. I get the error when I click either of those

Comment: What happens in runtime?

Comment: I get an empty DataGrid with no columns

Comment: And still no binding error in output window?

Comment: See my explanation below. I'm not too much familiar with designer tool, because I never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you bindings are probably incorrect. Remove leading slashes from your bindings, because what you are binding to is not a collection, so it has no current item.

Here is what I see in output when try your example:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: ''
>   property not found on 'current item of collection'
>   ''TransferSchedulesView' (HashCode=19117974)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=TransferSchedulesView/; DataItem='MainWindow'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='dataGrid1'); target
>   property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Here is my working example. If you run it, you'll see autogenerated columns:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataView}" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=WpfApplication1:MainWindow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=TransferSchedulesView}" />
```

---

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public TransferSchedulesView TransferSchedulesView { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TransferSchedulesView = new TransferSchedulesView(){DataView = CreateTable()};
        }

        private static DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("aaa");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("bbb");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ccc");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("sdaasdasd", "dsdsadasdasdsd", "sdasdadsadsadsd");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("sdaasdasd", "dsdsadasdasdsd", "sdasdadsadsadsd");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("sdaasdasd", "dsdsadasdasdsd", "sdasdadsadsadsd");
            return dataTable;
        }
    }

    public class TransferSchedulesView
    {
        public DataTable DataView { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. One other problem was that if there is no data in the table you won't get the column info